# How do I play the same sound on multiple clicks, using jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Currently, I have an explosion sound firing when my bubble's pop, using the explode effect from jQuery.  I'm wanting to be able to click on one bubble after another, without having to pause waiting for the other sound to finish.  I've tried using a variable to change to a different audio object with no luck.  Any help would be appreciated!

The same problem is happening in jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/xbrjp/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/xbrjp/1/)

My HTML

```
<body style="background:black;">
<style>
.circleBase {
    -webkit-border-radius: 999px;
    -moz-border-radius: 999px;
    border-radius: 999px;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}

.type1 {
     padding:20px;
    background: white;
    border:1px solid black;
    color:black;

}
</style>
<div class="circleBase type1" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
<div align="center">Bubble 1</div></div>
<div class="circleBase type1" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
<div align="center">Bubble 2</div></div>
<div class="circleBase type1" style="display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle;">
<div align="center">Bubble 3</div></div>
</body>
<script>
$( ".type1" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).toggle( "explode", {pieces: 50 }, 2000);

});
$(document).ready(function() {
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src',                              'http://www.soundjay.com/mechanical/sounds/explosion-01.mp3');
        //audioElement.load()
        $.get();
        audioElement.addEventListener("load", function() {
        audioElement.play();
        }, true);

        var audioElement2 = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement2.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.soundjay.com/mechanical/sounds/explosion-01.mp3');
        //audioElement.load()
        $.get();
        audioElement2.addEventListener("load", function() {
        audioElement2.play();
        }, true);

    var x = 0;
    if(x == 0) {
            $('.type1').click(function() {
            audioElement.play();
            });
            x = 1;
        }
        if(x == 1) {
            $('.type1').click(function() {
            audioElement2.play();
            });
            x = 0;
        }


        $('.pause').click(function() {
        audioElement.pause();
        });



});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would actually take the route of creating an `<audio>` element for each bubble:

http://jsfiddle.net/8qc9V/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".type1").click(function () {
        $(this).toggle("explode", {
            pieces: 50
        }, 2000);
        $(this).find('audio').get(0).play();
    });

    $('.type1').each(function() {
        $('<audio/>')
        .attr('src','http://www.soundjay.com/mechanical/sounds/explosion-01.mp3')
        .appendTo(this);
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you for that. That did work, but it was really laggy.  Is there anyway to make it faster?  If not, it's still a viable answer.

Comment: @user2128903 Here's another option that stores the audio elements in an array instead of the DOM. Seems faster, though I don't know how it would scale. http://jsfiddle.net/XevBg/

Comment: I would have expected that cloning an already existing node would have been extremely fast as well, unfortunately that doesn't seem to be the case yet. http://jsfiddle.net/xbrjp/4/